# How to show element of ArrayList converted to Object array by toArray methode?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How to show element of ArrayList converted to Object array by toArray methode?

I want to show array a's element (code in below) but It seem to just return address of the array. please help me ...T^T

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class testworld {

    static ArrayList<history> histories =new ArrayList<history>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

    history m1 =new history();
    m1.setAmount(""+0);
    m1.setUse("use");
    m1.setDate("date");
    m1.setTime("time");

    history m2 =new history();
    m2.setAmount(""+0);
    m2.setUse("use2");
    m2.setDate("date2");
    m2.setTime("time2");

    history m3 =new history();
    m3.setAmount(""+0);
    m3.setUse("use3");
    m3.setDate("date3");
    m3.setTime("time3");


    histories.add(0,m1);
    histories.add(1,m2);
    histories.add(2,m3);

    Object[] a = histories.toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println(a[0]);
    System.out.println(a[1]);
    System.out.println(a[2]);

    System.out.print(a);
    System.out.println(a);

    }
}
```

> [notepad.history@15db9742, notepad.history@6d06d69c,
>   notepad.history@7852e922]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there is the content of the array. You must overwrite the `toString()` method in the `history` class to see some useful information. 
The code you are asking for is

```
history[] a = new history[histories.size()];
a = histories.toArray(a);
```

I understand you are a beginner at java. Please read the javadocs or do some research before posting any further questions on stackoverflow. Also, read the java naming conventions. It 's `History` not `history`. Always use camel-case.